# LED vs. CFL Bulbs on Modified Sine Wave Inverter

Tags: electrical

I have been installing solar electric lighting systems in schools in Haiti for several years now using CFLs.

I have been thinking about installing LED bulbs instead.  I am using a DC to AC modified sine wave inverter at 60 Hz, 120 volt, 1750 watts.  Will the LEDs work as well as the CFLs do now?

Comment: I would definitely replace them with good quality LEDs as they fail, they are a far simpler devices. If you get the opportunity I would wire the lights separately with 12VDC (preferably with different wires that are designed for this application).

Answer (score 1):

It will work better - you don't even need the inverter, run the LEDs directly from the DC, they will like it *much* better than AC, and you will save power.

If you do choose to use AC you will have to convert it back to DC before the LED can use it, which commercial LEDs do automatically as part of the package.

I would suggest you don't use commercial LED's with an Edison base bulb, instead get special purpose LED's that run directly on DC. They are cheaper and simpler.

Does the DC voltage vary? That might complicate things.

Comment: Thank you, I have four schools now wired with CLF's and they also use the inverter power for amplification for their church services so we will probably not change to LED's.  Jim

Comment: You still can change to LED's it will work just fine, commercial LED's can work with AC. But I would suggest against it simply because LEDs are much more expensive than CFLs.

Comment: Another drawback of DC is that it's harder to step up/down efficiently -- you want high voltage/low current for thinner wires, but LED's generally want low voltage. You get the voltage conversion "for free" with CFL's because they are churned out by the millions, but if you have to buy efficient DC-DC switching power supplies for your custom DC power system it's going to cost more.

Comment: That 'free' voltage conversion done by CFL's is often done with cheap power transistors and other compenents tuned for 60Hz that might not like long term use of the stepped sine wave coming out of an inverter. Relatively simple LED's are far less picky about such things. http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1281325 xxx  http://www.instructables.com/id/Useful-components-in-the-base-of-a-burned-out-CFL-/

Comment: But how are you going to efficiently step down the 48VDC or 100VDC you need for efficient power transfer without cheap power transistors and other components? You could run 5VDC to reduce the need to step down, but then you're looking at 20A of current for 100W of lighting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason to retrofit your previous installs with LEDs unless they are trying to squeeze just a little more power out of the system (energy savings won't do you any good unless you need the energy for something else). There is the possibility that choosing LEDs when the CFLs need replacing would reduce long term costs, but there is no advantage to throwing out the working CFLs.

You might look at the cost/benefit of using DC LED lighting on future installs. With LEDs on DC, you'd save energy (both the energy the light consumes and the inverter losses) so might be able to meet needs with fewer panels and a smaller inverter. Even if initial costs are higher, the long life of the LED's might tip the balance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a solar installer in Spain and I am finding the cheap AC/DC compact converters within LED light bulbs designed for AC use are causing high harmonic interference with the main system inverter, causing the inverter to run much hotter and sometimes burn out the diodes on the power board. I would stick with CFL low energy bulbs (although they also have AC/DC compact converters they don't seem to have the same effect) for safety and reliability reasons. More of a problem for high frequency inverters than low frequency.

Comment: Odd -- is it a power factor problem? Cheap LED bulbs use capacitive droppers/current limiters, which have *atrocious* power factor...